# Why OJ reports Runtime Error for this piece of code?

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime-error

I recently begin trying POJ using Java.I came across a [problem](http://poj.org/problem?id=2255)(also available [here](http://acm.uva.es/p/v5/536.html) on UVa),which is know as **Tree Recovery**.Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Main {

```
static String pre, in;
static char[] post = new char[100];
static int len;

public static void solve(int p1, int p2, int m1, int m2) {
    if (p1 > p2)
        return;
    int i;
    for (i = m1; i <= m2; i++) {
        if(in.charAt(i)==pre.charAt(p1))
            break;
    }
    post[--len] = pre.charAt(p1);
    if (p1 == p2)
        return;
    solve(p1 + (i + 1) - m1, p2, i + 1, m2);
    solve(p1 + 1, p1 + i - m1, m1, i - 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        pre = sc.next();
        in = sc.next();
        len = pre.length();
        solve(0, len - 1, 0, len - 1);
        System.out.println(post);
    }
}
```

}

The code runs well on the given test cases with the default compile option of eclipse.However it reports *Runtime Error* when I submit.I'm wondering how this could happen.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the engine is running different test cases than you have tried and your code has a defect that produces a runtime error on those cases. It is likely to be caused by some kind of an illegal access.

For instance;

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    pre = sc.next();
    in = sc.next();
...
}
```

looks suspicious. Are you sure `sc` has two `next()`s available after a one `hasNextLine()` check?

Furthermore; check for array indices: `if(in.charAt(i)==pre.charAt(p1))` and `post[--len] = pre.charAt(p1)`. You can try using assertions before each of such lines: `assert(post.length < len - 1 && pre.length() < p1)`.

Can you think of any inputs that those lines might fail? You are probably trying to access an index at an array or string that does not exist. Test your code against such corner-cases.